# Getting builtins.NameError when using a Code block in Chameleon

Tags: python, chameleon, template-tal

I expected this snippet to work:

```
<div class="footer">
  <? python import time; year = time.strftime('%Y') ?>
  &copy; Copyright 2008-${year}, Agendaless Consulting.
</div>
```

It instead fails with:

```
NameError: year

 - Expression: " python import time; year = time.strftime('%Y') ?>
      &copy; Copyright 2008-${year}, Agendaless Consulting."
 - Filename:   /tmp/foo/foo/foo/foo/templates/mytemplate.pt
 - Location:   (74:8)
 - Source:     ... python import time; year = time.strftime('%Y') ?>
                  ^
 - Arguments:  view: <function my_view at 0x7f48d0bca3b0>
               repeat: {...} (0)
               req: <Request - at 0x7f48d29173d0>
               renderer_name: templates/mytemplate.pt
               project: foo
               request: <Request - at 0x7f48d29173d0>
               renderer_info: <RendererHelper - at 0x7f48d0bd1450>
               context: <DefaultRootFactory None at 0x7f48d2917450>
```

As background, the idea is to avoid having to update the year every year:

```
<div class="footer">
  &copy; Copyright 2008-2012, Agendaless Consulting.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be whitespace between the first `?` and `python`. The following works well:

```
<div class="footer">
  <?python import time; year = time.strftime('%Y') ?>
  &copy; Copyright 2008-${year}, Agendaless Consulting.
</div>
```

Weird.

Comment: Perhaps this should be reported as a bug. I think the syntax that includes a space character is much easier to read. It's a shame if it doesn't parse.